# Jump is triggered twice per click in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

hello i am currently trying to make a jumping game in pygame a lot  like the chrome dino game. i have made some simple code to draw a square and make it jump. i will my code dow n bellow. my problem is with the jumping part. whenever i press w wichis the the jump button the square jumps multiple times(usauly 2 times). good people of stack overflow please help a man in need.
here is my code

```py
import pygame
    
pygame.init()

screen_width = 500
screen_height = 400
isJump = False
y = 350
x = 50
BLUE=(0,0,255)
run = True

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
screen.fill((0,0,0))
pygame.display.set_caption("syoma n9ot intelent")
pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE,(x,y,50,50))

while run:
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        for a in range (1,250): 
            y -= .5
            screen.fill((0,0,0))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE,(x,y,50,50))
            pygame.display.flip()

            
        for a in range (1,250):
            y += .5
            screen.fill((0,0,0))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE,(x,y,50,50))
            pygame.display.flip()

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `KEYDOWN` event instead of `pygame.key.get_pressed()`.

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a sequence with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`. Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button and get continuous movement.

The keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. The `KEYDOWN` event occurs once every time a key is pressed. `KEYUP` occurs once every time a key is released. Use the keyboard events for a single action or a step-by-step movement.

Use [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) to control the frames per second and thus the game speed.

The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time. See [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick):

> This method should be called once per frame.

That means that the loop:

> ```py
> clock = pygame.time.Clock()
> run = True
> while run:
>    clock.tick(100)
> ```

runs 100 times per second.

Do not control the game with an extra loop in the application or event loop. Use the application loop. Use the variables `isJump` and `jumpCount` to control the jump. Set the variable `isJump = True` and `jumpCount = 20` when <kbd>w</kbd> is started pressed. Decrement `jumpCount` in the application loop and change the y position of the player. Set `isJump = False` if `jumpCount == -20`:

---

Complete example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen_width = 500
screen_height = 400
isJump = False
jumpCount = 0
y = 350
x = 50
BLUE=(0,0,255)
run = True

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption("syoma n9ot intelent")
pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE,(x,y,50,50))

while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                isJump = True
                jumpCount = 20

    if isJump:
        if jumpCount > 0:
            y -= 5
        elif jumpCount <= 0:
            y += 5
        jumpCount -= 1
        if jumpCount == -20:
            isJump = False
          
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE,(x,y,50,50))
    pygame.display.flip()
```